# R- create new variable with mutate on a range of rows

Tags: r

this question is similar to my previous question.

I am working on financial data that I want to "roll" on the first day of the expiration month. 
Here is my code, that is wrong, at least in the `mutate` part :

```
newdf2<-Data %>%
  mutate(Close_exp= ifelse(as.Date(Date==Echeance)-10, lead(Close,1), Close))

newdf2= newdf2[!duplicated(newdf2$Date),]
```

What I'm trying to do is the following : create a new variable called `Close_exp` takes the value of `Close`, except for the 10 days before the day of `Echeance`. In this case, it will take the following Close value.

**EDIT: In other words, since `Echeance` is the 10th day of some specific months, it should give the 'following close' value from the first day of the month of `Echeance`, to the 10th of the Echeance month. For example, say Echeance is the 10th of September, I am looking for a way to select the 10 first days of September.**

This is a glimpse of my data :

```
Date                Echeance            Compens.  Open  Haut   Bas Close 

1 1998-03-27 00:00:00 1998-09-10 00:00:00     125.   828   828   820  820.   197     
2 1998-03-27 00:00:00 1998-11-10 00:00:00     128.   847   847   842  842.   124     
3 1998-03-27 00:00:00 1999-01-11 00:00:00     131.   858   858   858  858.     2     
4 1998-03-30 00:00:00 1998-09-10 00:00:00     125.   821   821   820  820.    38     
5 1998-03-30 00:00:00 1998-11-10 00:00:00     129.   843   843   843  843.     1     
6 1998-03-30 00:00:00 1999-01-11 00:00:00     131.   860   860   860  860.     5
```

Here is the data in the Dput format :

```
 structure(list(Date = structure(c(890956800, 890956800, 890956800, 
 891216000, 891216000, 891216000, 891302400, 891302400, 891302400, 
 891388800, 891388800, 891388800, 891388800, 891475200, 891475200, 
 891475200, 891475200, 891561600, 891561600, 891561600), class =      c("POSIXct", 
 "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Echeance = structure(c(905385600, 
 910656000, 916012800, 905385600, 910656000, 916012800, 905385600, 
 910656000, 916012800, 905385600, 910656000, 916012800, 936921600, 
 905385600, 910656000, 916012800, 936921600, 905385600, 910656000, 
 916012800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Compens. =      c(125.00819413, 
 128.36207251, 130.80125679, 125.00819413, 128.51452153, 131.10615482, 
 125.16064315, 128.81941957, 130.95370581, 125.00819413, 128.97186858, 
 130.95370581, 131.10615482, 124.85574512, 129.1243176, 130.95370581, 
 131.10615482, 123.63615298, 128.36207251, 130.49635876), Open = c(828, 
 847, 858, 821, 843, 860, 820, 844, 860, 820, 846, 859, 860, 819, 
 846, NA, NA, 817, 845, NA), Haut = c(828, 847, 858, 821, 843, 
 860, 821, 845, 860, 820, 846, 859, 860, 819, 847, NA, NA, 817, 
 845, NA), Bas = c(820, 842, 858, 820, 843, 860, 820, 844, 860, 
 820, 846, 859, 860, 819, 846, NA, NA, 811, 842, NA), Close = c(819.999999969324, 
 841.999999974421, 858.00000000198, 819.999999969324, 842.999999992542, 
 859.999999972627, 820.999999987445, 845.000000028785, 859.000000020102, 
 819.999999969324, 845.999999981311, 859.000000020102, 859.999999972627, 
 819.000000016798, 846.999999999432, NA, NA, 811.000000003019, 
 841.999999974421, NA), Vol_Q = c(197, 124, 2, 38, 1, 5, 56, 85, 
 10, 10, 103, 10, 2, 30, 70, 0, 0, 145, 150, 0), Bloc_Q = c(NA_real_, 
 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Trades = c(NA_real_, 
 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `Vol_€` =      c(1231330.7121805, 
 795844.849562, 13080.125679, 237515.568847, 6425.7260765, 32776.538705, 
 350449.80082, 547482.5331725, 65476.852905, 62504.097065, 664205.123187, 
 65476.852905, 13110.615482, 187283.61768, 451935.1116, 0, 0, 
 896362.109105, 962715.543825, 0), O.I. = c(170, 123, 2, 188, 
 124, 7, 244, 184, 17, 192, 267, 27, 2, 222, 337, 27, 2, 347, 
 474, 27)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
 "data.frame"))
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `as.Date(Date==Echeance)` is the source of the error, the comparison `==` returns a logical value and you are trying to coerce it (`FALSE/TRUE`) to class `Date`!

Comment: @RuiBarradas I see, thank you for your reply. In this case, how can I put a condition on the 10 previous days ?

Comment: Can you post your sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(newdf)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(newdf, 20))`.

Comment: I put the data in the dput format. It is "Data" and not "newdf" as it is the one I'm working on.

Comment: So `Close_exp` is equal to `Close` except if `Date == Echeance - 10` where it takes what value? The next `Close` value? (That's what `lead(Close, 1)` is, in this case.)

Comment: `Close_exp` is equal to `Close` except for the 10 days before the day where `Date == Echeance`, in this case, take the next `Close` value @RuiBarradas

Comment: I edited my question @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure whether the following does what you want.
Some of the days in `Echeance` are equal to `10`, others to `11`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

Data %>%
  mutate(Close_exp = ifelse(day(Echeance) %in% 10:11, Close[day(Date) %in% 1:10], Close))
```

Comment: Not exactly, I changed it to this : `if (month(Date) == month(Echeance)) {
newdf3<-Data %>%
  mutate(Close_exp = ifelse(day(Date) %in% 1:10, lead(Close,1), Close))
}`   
Which translates what I want to do, but I think my code is wrong, can you please check it?

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work `newdf3<-Data %>%
  mutate(Close_exp = ifelse(month(Date)==month(Echeance)& day(Date) %in% 1:10, lead(Close,1), Close))`